# Copy Worksheet to New Workbook Doesn't Allow onEdit Apps Script to Run Properly

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a Google spreadsheet template with a worksheet that's called "CollegeTracker" that users can right click on the tab, and "copy to" their workbook.  However, my onEdit function from the Apps Script is not working.

```
function onEdit()
{
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "CollegeTracker" ) 
  { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();

    var range = s.getRange(r.getRow(),r.getColumn()); 
    var data = range.getValue();
    var schoolRange = s.getRange(r.getRow(),1);
    var schoolData = schoolRange.getValue();
    var deadlineRange = s.getRange(r.getRow(),3);
    var deadlineData = deadlineRange.getValue();

    Logger.log(r.getRow());
    Logger.log(r.getColumn());
    Logger.log(data);
```

This is the beginning of my code.  I added a couple loggers to see what's going on.  I typed something in cell A2 but the logger shows row 1 column 1, or A1.  I tried in a couple other cells but it always return A1 as the active cell.  I repeating this in cell A6 and E7 but the logger always return A1.  However, this is reading correctly in the template.  I wonder if it's a permissions issue where I have to allow getActiveCell() to work.  If this is the case, how would I go about doing this?  I copy and pasted the code from my template and pasted into the script editor and it works fine.  I can certainly make multiple copies of my script but if I figure this out, I think one copy can work for multiple sheets should be fine.  Do you know what's blocking getActiveCell() from working?  And if it's the permissions, how do I go about solving this?

Update:
I've been continuing my tests and realized that getActiveSheet() is still thinking that my template sheet is active even though I am working on a new sheet.  I wonder if there is a way to determine the sheet I'm working in regardless of the Workbook I'm in.

Thanks!

-Ray

Comment: And if you use the event object? (All triggered functions can bind an event object, as indicated in every example of trigger functions in documentation.)

Comment: You're using active cell but the edit event has an `e` argument that contains the range that has been edited. Take a look at [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'm still new to this so I'm sure this is because of a gap in knowledge.  I have this error "TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined." When I wrote something simple 

function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  Logger.log(range);
}

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?